# How to full text search more than one "model" field using Ecto and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm using this search function in my controller:

```
def search(query, search_term) do
    (from u in query,
    where: fragment("to_tsvector(?) @@ plainto_tsquery(?)", u.name, ^search_term),
    order_by: fragment("ts_rank(to_tsvector(?), plainto_tsquery(?)) DESC", u.name, ^search_term))
  end
```

It's working for just one field of my model. I would like to search all fields or be able to search a selected few (name_label, contacts, ...) at the same time.
How to do it?

Comment: It may make sense to create a view to make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(to_tsvector(col1) || to_tsvector(col2))) @@ plainto_tsquery(?)
```

to concatenate text search vectors.

Comment: Thank you. And when I want to search all fields at the same time is there a not so verbose alternative?

Comment: You can also concatenate the relevant text fields first with `||` and apply `to_tsvector` to the result. But no, there is no magic shorthand. Normally people don't want full text search on the primary key column...